# iOS, Overriding cellForRowAtIndexPath to return custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In order to add a property to a cell which I can use for identifying a row, I've created a custom cell which is subclassed from UITableViewCell.  That part seems to work fine, but when I try to implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I'm unable to get my custom cell pointer, and thus cannot access that property.  Do I need to override cellForRowAtIndexPath?

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";

    NLSTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[NLSTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    NSLog(@"indexPath: %ld", indexPath.row);
    NSDictionary *cellDict = [self.sql getTitleAndIdForRow:indexPath.row];

    NSArray *keys = [cellDict allKeys];
    id rowId = [keys objectAtIndex:0];
    id title = [cellDict objectForKey:rowId];

    cell.textLabel.text = title;
    cell.rowId = (NSUInteger)rowId;
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    //This message returns a UITableViewCell, not a my custom NLSTableViewCell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];
    string = cell.textLabel.text;
    NSUInteger rowId = cell.rowId;
    NSLog(@"id: %ld, title: %@", rowId, string);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about casting?

```
NLSTableViewCell *cell = (NLSTableViewCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 1):

In your viewDidLoad 2 things to check.
1. That you register the class  for the table view cell. 
2. That you use the custom class in your registration statement.  ie.

[myTableView registerClass:[**YOUR_CUSTOM_CELL_CLASS** class] forCellReuseIdentifier:**YOUR_CUSTOM_CELL_CLASS_REUSE_ID**];

Casting the subclassed Table view cell in the dequeue statement did not work for me.

Cheers!